# IPv6 network range

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I was learning about IPv6 in order to build an internal network port scanner (this means a private network to which one is connected) I wasn't able to find a way to know the network range with the submask, let me illustrate it with an example :

IPv4 : 192.168.2.32 with a sub mask of 255.255.255.0 means that the 192.168.2 part of the IPv4 represents the network and the 32 represents the device ip. So, when scanning the network I know I have to scan the ips in the following range : 192.168.2.0 -- 192.168.2.255

IPv6: fd04:ad:32be:: . I know the first 64 bits represent the network if /64 , but while scanning an internal network with this IPv6 address how do I know the range to scan like in IPv4 ?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Did you do the math? On a standard IPv6 `/64` network, there are `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` possible addresses, and scanning `1,000,000` addresses per second, it will take you over `584,542` years to scan one `/64` network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have older network equipment and are in an enterprise, rapid sequential scans of large swaths of IPv6 space is not a good idea (and isn't really a gd idea in general).

W/r/t "ranges", this is from current rev `nmap`

> IPv6 addresses can be specified by their fully qualified IPv6 address or hostname or with CIDR notation for subnets. Octet ranges aren't yet supported for IPv6.

[This](http://www.ipaddressguide.com/ipv6-cidr) is a randomly selected range-to-subnet converter.

Consider using ICMPv6 Neighbor Discovery vs sequential scans and also consider using DHCP logs and switch/router logs to get individual IPv6 addresses vs use ranges and perform sequential scans.

Also, unless you know what you're doing or are trying to take a deep-dive into low-level network programming, don't reinvent the wheel and just use `nmap`.

Finally, this is prbly a more appropriate question for serverfault and can/should likely be closed.